# Multiple Count staements in one sql query

Tags: sql, performance, count

Table A consists of columns LIKE Region, mileage and Project Number
Table B consists of Project Number, folder name and document names
I need a result set where I need to give the count of each document under each project along with its region and mileage details

My query is as below:

```
SELECT PN.[ProjectNumber] AS 'Project ID' ,
       PN.[Number2]       AS 'Mileage'    ,
       PN.[Region]        AS  'Region'    ,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE PN.[ProjectNumber] in ( SELECT [Project Site] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[_TPG_DocumentReport] DR where [Project Site] <> '_PSEP' aND DR.Stage LIKE '%Stage 1' And LeafName like '%'+ '[_]'+'162'+'[_]'+'%' ) ) AS 'WORKORDER' ,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE PN.[ProjectNumber] in ( SELECT [Project Site] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[_TPG_DocumentReport] DR where [Project Site] <> '_PSEP' aND DR.Stage LIKE '%Stage 1' And LeafName like '%'+ '[_]'+'047'+'[_]'+'%' ) ) AS 'HighLevel' ,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE PN.[ProjectNumber] in ( SELECT [Project Site] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[_TPG_DocumentReport] DR where [Project Site] <> '_PSEP' aND DR.Stage LIKE '%Stage 1' And LeafName like '%'+ '[_]'+'054'+'[_]'+'%' ) ) AS 'Study'     ,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE PN.[ProjectNumber] in ( SELECT [Project Site] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[_TPG_DocumentReport] DR where [Project Site] <> '_PSEP' aND DR.Stage LIKE '%Stage 1' And LeafName like '%'+ '[_]'+'138'+'[_]'+'%' ) ) AS 'Decision'  ,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE PN.[ProjectNumber] in ( SELECT [Project Site] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[_TPG_DocumentReport] DR where [Project Site] <> '_PSEP' aND DR.Stage LIKE '%Stage 1' And LeafName like '%'+ '[_]'+'213'+'[_]'+'%' ) ) AS 'Record'    ,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE PN.[ProjectNumber] in ( SELECT [Project Site] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[_TPG_DocumentReport] DR where [Project Site] <> '_PSEP' aND DR.Stage LIKE '%Stage 1' And LeafName like '%'+ '[_]'+'164'+'[_]'+'%' ) ) AS 'Work'      ,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE PN.[ProjectNumber] in ( SELECT [Project Site] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[_TPG_DocumentReport] DR where [Project Site] <> '_PSEP' aND DR.Stage LIKE '%Stage 1' And LeafName like '%'+ '[_]'+'052'+'[_]'+'%' ) ) AS 'Attribute'  
FROM [Projectserver_Reporting_TPG].[dbo].[_TPG_ProjectInformation] PN
```

I am getting expected Result set but not sure how to make the query better to have less number of lines and better performance. This is my result set:

```
Project ID          Mileage Region          WORKORDER HighLevel Study Decision Record Work Attribute
------------------- ------- --------------- --------- --------- ----- -------- ------ ---- ---------
1024                NULL    Transmission        0         0       0       0       0     0      0
41-05-A             NULL    Inland              0         0       0       0       0     0      0
35-351              NULL    Northern            0         0       0       0       0     0      0
404                 9.00    Transmission        1         1       1       1       1     1      1
36-6588             NULL    Northern            0         0       0       0       0     0      0
Project Excellence  NULL    NULL                0         0       0       0       0     0      0
49-28               2.39    SDG&E               1         1       1       1       1     1      1
37-18-K             2.00    Pacific Coast       1         1       1       1       0     1      1
42-57               NULL    Orange Coast        0         0       0       0       0     0      0
1003LT2             NULL    Transmission        0         0       0       0       0     0      0
247 ID403-T1        NULL    Transmission        0         0       0       0       0     0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

I set up some tables to test this out, using a blend of fake and demo data:

```
CREATE TABLE [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (
      ProjectNumber VARCHAR(20)
    , Number2 NUMERIC(4,2)
    , Region VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('1024',NULL,'Transmission');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('41-05-A',NULL,'Inland');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('35-351',NULL,'Northern');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('404',9.00,'Transmission');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('36-6588',NULL,'Northern');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('Project Excellence',NULL,'NULL');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('49-28',2.39,'SDG&E');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('37-18-K',2.00,'Pacific Coast');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('42-57',NULL,'Orange Coast');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('1003LT2',NULL,'Transmission');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_ProjectInformation] (ProjectNumber,Number2,Region) VALUES ('247 ID403-T1',NULL,'Transmission');

CREATE TABLE [_TPG_DocumentReport] (
      [Project Site] VARCHAR(20)
    , [Stage] VARCHAR(20)
    , [LeafName] VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('404','Some Stage 1','This_Code_162_B');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('404','This Stage 1','That_Code_047_R');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('404','That Stage 1','Some_Code_054_E');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('404','Miss Stage 1','This_Code_138_C');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('404','Wood Stage 1','In_Code_213_E');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('404','Step Stage 1','Out_Code_164_C');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('404','Done Stage 1','Build_Code_052_C');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('49-28','Some Stage 1','This_Code_162_B');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('49-28','This Stage 1','That_Code_047_R');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('49-28','That Stage 1','Some_Code_054_E');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('49-28','Miss Stage 1','This_Code_138_C');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('49-28','Wood Stage 1','In_Code_213_E');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('49-28','Step Stage 1','Out_Code_164_C');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('49-28','Done Stage 1','Build_Code_052_C');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('37-18-K','Some Stage 1','This_Code_162_B');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('37-18-K','This Stage 1','That_Code_047_R');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('37-18-K','That Stage 1','Some_Code_054_E');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('37-18-K','Miss Stage 1','This_Code_138_C');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('37-18-K','Step Stage 1','Out_Code_164_C');
INSERT INTO [_TPG_DocumentReport] ([Project Site],[Stage],[LeafName]) VALUES ('37-18-K','Done Stage 1','Build_Code_052_C');
```

Then I took to turning this into a PIVOT query to reduce the number of Table Scans (though likely index seeks in your case):

```
SELECT
      [Project ID]
    , [Mileage]
    , [Region]
    , [Stage]
    , ISNULL([162],0) AS 'WORKORDER'
    , ISNULL([047],0) AS 'HighLevel'
    , ISNULL([054],0) AS 'Study'    
    , ISNULL([138],0) AS 'Decision' 
    , ISNULL([213],0) AS 'Record'   
    , ISNULL([164],0) AS 'Work'     
    , ISNULL([052],0) AS 'Attribute'
FROM (
    SELECT
        PN.[ProjectNumber] AS 'Project ID' ,
        PN.[Number2]       AS 'Mileage'    ,
        PN.[Region]        AS 'Region'     ,
        DR.[Stage]         AS 'Stage'      ,
        DR.[LeafCode]      AS 'LeafCode'
    FROM [_TPG_ProjectInformation] PN
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [Project Site], [Stage], substring(leafname,patindex('%_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_%',leafname)+1,3) AS LeafCode
        FROM [_TPG_DocumentReport]
        ) DR ON PN.[ProjectNumber] = DR.[Project Site] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
    ) Z
    --Note, no further specifying of [Project Site] needed, thus no filter for '_PSEP'.
        PIVOT (
            COUNT(LeafCode)
            FOR LeafCode IN
                ([162],[047],[054],[138],[213],[164],[052])
        ) P
```

Instead of the 7 table scans on [_TPG_DocumentReport], the plan came up with only 1. While A bit more computationally expensive in the query plans, this one came up as half as costly overall. I hope it helps.

EDIT: Updated to include Stage per comments.

Comment: It worked great but I have a question though, How can I implement this code for different stage values? For ex in the code we have Stage 1 but what if I need few documents from Stage 2 and so on?

Comment: You could either change the criteria on run time, easily done if you're running it from a web form or some such, but otherwise you could also just remove the criteria and select Stage in the left join and outer select to get the stage selected and displayed.

Comment: I am sorry I not very much familiar with query writing just a beginner..I did not get what you meant

Comment: So, the criteria is in the WHERE clause "WHERE Stage LIKE '%Stage 1'", and Stage 1 could be substituted for whatever you like, '%Stage 2', etc. Alternately, you could remove the line, and add stage to both SELECT clauses:

SELECT
PN.[ProjectNumber] AS 'Project ID' ,
PN.[Number2]       AS 'Mileage'    ,
PN.[Region]        AS 'Region'     ,
DR.[LeafCode]      AS 'LeafCode'   ,
DR.[Stage]         AS 'Stage'

and:

SELECT
  [Project ID]
, [Mileage]
, [Region]
, [Stage]
, ISNULL([162],0) AS 'WORKORDER'
    , ...

Please upvote and select my answer if you do implement it.

Comment: Hi,Scenario here is a doc with code 054 may be available in both Stage 1 and Stage 2 and I need to update the count for both the stages in different columns. How can I handle this? There are up to 7 stages and this document can be present in any of these folders

Comment: Hmm, so just so I understand correctly, you want the count to represent the stage that a particular code has achieved?This can be done. If so, is there ever any concern that Stage 1 records will not be present when the data indicates Stage 2? It might be more proper to select the stage number itself in the inner query, and select the max of that rather than counting if this is the case. Or is it more that you want rows for each stage that is present?

Comment: I need rows for each stage that is present.My code would be like below in extension to the initial one I posted               ( SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE PN.[ProjectNumber] in (SELECT [Project Site] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[_TPG_DocumentReport] DR where DR.Stage LIKE '%Stage 2' And LeafName like '%'+ '[_]'+'164'+'[_]'+'%')) AS'Work2',(SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE PN.[ProjectNumber] in (SELECT [Project Site] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[_TPG_DocumentReport] DR where DR.Stage LIKE '%Stage 3' And LeafName like '%'+ '[_]'+'052'+'[_]'+'%'))AS'Attribute3'

Comment: Check out the Edit - The Stage column can be parsed to be only a numeric value if need be, and should be more useful in this form. If you need it as a column per stage, that can be quite a bother as a dynamic SQL function is required to pick up the possible stages and then construct the query. MSSQL doesn't have a dynamic pivot function.

Comment: I need a column per stage :(..that is where my code is failing due to performance..is there any other solution??Thank you so much for your time and support

Comment: Then it's going to have to be a dynamic pivot statement that can't be achieved in a view alone. The target application should decide your approach there - where is the data selected from this view going to end up?

Comment: I am building the report using report builder and it will be  displayed on a Report Viewer web part on SharePoint Page

Comment: Then I suggest doing some of the work using the Report Engine. Use the query I constructed above (or parse out the last numeric parts of the stage column), and use a table control with an additional column grouping of the stage column selected. I would suggest a grouping order under the data columns. Read up on Pivot tables in the Report Builder. Good luck with the data set.

Comment: Hi Jaaz, your query helped me to improve the performance.I manipulated the front end report as suggested by you

Comment: @user3645588 Great, an upvote or checked as a solution that helped would be appreciated.